# Fine user mobile location with My Location feature of google maps

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, mobile, geolocation

Does My Location feature of google maps has any API ?
I need to localize users in the iphone/android/blackberry phones browsers, starting by trying to get the GPS location, then Cell ID, etc ... exactly what My Location does! But after 1 hour searching the web, i found nothing!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is a HTML? If so, use [HTML5 Geo Location API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). It works on Android/iPhone and the more recent BlackBerry devices. Example of use:

**Updated** to set *enableHighAccuracy* to true so the device will attempt to get high accuracy location

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationHandler, locationErrorHandler, 
                                         {enableHighAccuracy:true});

function locationHandler(position)
{
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var lng = position.coords.longitude;
}
```